# jqPlot meter gauge extender

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jqplot

I want to use meter gauge to show ranged KPI (date range) and it's state at the moment.
As meter gauge takes only numbers as intervals and it's value, I can use time in millis to do so. But I need ticks labels to show date in apoppriate format i.e. 01/01/2010.
I previously used bar chart to render range KPI, but it looks ugly :) However I was able to set an extender to do something like this:

```
function dateOnYAxisExtender() {
  /**
   * Проверить поддерживает ли браузер функцию toLocaleDateString()
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  function toLocaleDateStringSupportsLocales() {
      try {
          new Date().toLocaleDateString('i');
      } catch (e) {
          return e.name === 'RangeError';
      }
      return false;
  }
  this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
      formatter: function (format, value) {
          return $.jqplot.sprintf(toLocaleDateStringSupportsLocales()
                                      ? convertToDateOutOfTheBox(value)
                                      : convertToDateCalculated(value));
      }
  };
}
```

where in `convertToDateOutOfTheBox(value)` or `convertToDateCalculated(value)` time in millis simply converted to date string. As a result my chart renders date labels and it was ok.
So my question is how can I achive same result using meter gauge chart?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work in plain jQPlot?

Comment: What do you mean? Extender for a bar chart? If so - yes it works.

Comment: No, what you want in the gauge... Plain jqplot (without PrimeFaces). If it does not work there, it can never work in the PF charts.

Comment: I want to override meter gauge to render tick labels as a date string. I don't know is jqplot(plain) able to do this or not (this is the essence of my question). If it's able I'll try to repeat such behavior with PF charts. p.s. may be my english so bad that I can't clearly express my thoughts? :(